# How to represent microbuses (hail and ride transport) in GTFS (for OpenTripPlanner server)

Tags: general-transit-feed-specification, opentripplanner

I am doing transit database for my city in GTFS format. And I have an problem with microbuses (hail-and-ride transport), because this transport doesn't have stops. As a workaround, I can made stops every 100-200 meters, but maybe it's possible to do easier.